# Replace package inside package in Python

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I'm trying to replace the use of the `datetime` package inside the `calendarweek` package with a custom package that adds additional functionality to it (`extensions.datetime`), which looks as follows:

```py
from datetime import *

class date(date):
    @property
    def test(self):
        print("test")
```

To make sure that my package is used I replaced the module reference in `sys.modules` from the `__init__.py` inside my `extensions` package (EDIT: patching `datetime` before importing `calendarweek`):

```py
import datetime as _datetime
import extensions.datetime
sys.modules[_datetime.__name__] = extensions.datetime

import calendarweek as _calendarweek
import extensions.calendarweek
sys.modules[_calendarweek.__name__] = extensions.calendarweek
```

However, when I run `calendarweek.CalendarWeek()[0].__class__` I would expect it to be `extensions.datetime.date`, however it's `datetime.date`. I tried reloading both modules using `importlib.reload()`.
I run those commands inside a `main.py`, which is at the same directory-level as the `extensions` package:

```py
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import extensions  # importing the extensions-package first to make sure only they're replacement is taking effect

from extensions.calendarweek import CalendarWeek

def main():
    CalendarWeek()[0].__class__

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How do I replace the use of the builtin `datetime` package, globally, so that every tried use of the builtin package points to my customized implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details about how and where you are running the line `calendarweek.CalendarWeek()[0].__class__`? In the same file or a separate file/script? How and when are you running your monkey patch? Any module that is executed before your monkey patch may have a reference to the old modules

Comment: Not sure what your calendarweek  patch contains but I tried your script with the datetime patch and it worked for me -  top of the file `import extensions; from datetime import date` and in the main function `print(date(2022, 1, 1).__class__)` gave `<class 'extensions.datetime.date'>`

Comment: The `calendarweek` package uses the `date` class, which isn't replaced with my patch. `calendarweek.CalendarWeek()[0]` returns a `date` instance for the first day of the week. And that instance should be an instance of the patch.

Comment: Try doing all the patching of `datetime` before you import `calendarweek` or your patched version in `extensions/__init__.py`, you need to have patched the module before

Comment: I tried (see updated question), still no effect.

Comment: And what's even more weird: `calendarweek.calendarweek.date(2022, 1, 1)` is an instance of the patched version - `calendarweek.calendarweek.CalendarWeek()[0]` isn't.

Comment: Did a bit of digging, under the hood `CalendarWeek()[0]` get a datetime using `datetime.strptime()` and then converts that to a date using the `date()` method. Your issue is that the patched version of `datetime.datetime` still uses the original date class - `import extensions; from extensions.datetime import datetime; print(datetime.now().date().__class__)` gives `<class 'datetime.date'>`

Comment: I see. How can we then patch it? I guess it might be possible to patch around again by overriding every possible use case were the original package is used, but that's not very clean and consistent. Is there another, more cleaner solution that provides full access to override **any** use?

Comment: It's probably possible to patch every single use, consistent and especially clean methods of doing so are not looking likely though. May be time to start looking for a different solution

Comment: Tried overriding using `_datetime.datetime.date = extensions.datetime.date`. Still no success. I guess then I have to find other solutions, how frustrating - thank you for your time anyways! :)